# Angularjs : directive not called

Tags: angularjs

I have an input :

```
<table>
...
<td style="width:59px"><input ng-model="myModel.propertyOne"  ng-blur="persistValue(myModel)"  enter-as-tab></td>
<td style="width:59px"><input ng-model="myModel.propertyTwo"  ng-blur="persistValue(myModel)"  enter-as-tab></td>
```

with its directive

```
angular.module('bioandbioApp').directive('enterAsTab', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var elementToFocus = element.next('td').find('input')[1];
                if(angular.isDefined(elementToFocus))
                    elementToFocus.focus();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

This directive is called when user press Enter, and set the focus to the input of the next  tag.

My problem is that the directive is called but elementToFocus.focus() is not called so the focus is not set.

I don't understand why. Does anyone know?

http://jsfiddle.net/tomy29/vpaqt29d/105/

Thanks

Comment: Care to create a fiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code

```
$(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input')[0];
```

Currently, `this` is the input field of the current td. So, by that, you can  find the input to the next of the current td.

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vpaqt29d/106/)

Comment: Your solution is not taking the focus to the next input element when in the age input box. I think the proper solution would be to take the focus to the next input element in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the parent first and then go the next element.

Try the below code:

```
var app = angular.module("ap", []);

app.controller("con", function ($scope) {

    $scope.persons = [{
        name: 'Susan',
        age: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Peter',
        age: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Jack',
        age: 2
    }];
});

app.directive('enterAsTab', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("parent");
                console.log(element.parent())
                var elementToFocus = element.parent().next('td').find('input')[0];
                console.log("next element");
                console.log(elementToFocus);
                if (angular.isDefined(elementToFocus)) elementToFocus.focus();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/vpaqt29d/108/)

--EDIT--
This definitely can be optimized but a crud way of doing is as below:

```
<body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
     <h4>Pressing <i>Enter/Return</i> in the <i>Age</i> field will iterate through the ages</h4>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='person in persons'>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name="personName" ng-model="person.name" enter-as-tab />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type='number' name="personAge" ng-model="person.age" enter-as-tab/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

var app = angular.module("ap", []);

app.controller("con", function ($scope) {

    $scope.persons = [{
        name: 'Susan',
        age: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Peter',
        age: 1
    }, {
        name: 'Jack',
        age: 2
    }];
});

app.directive('enterAsTab', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("parent");
                console.log(element.parent())
                var elementToFocus = element.parent().next('td').find('input')[0];
                console.log('next element');
                console.log(elementToFocus);
                if (angular.isDefined(elementToFocus)) {
                    elementToFocus.focus();
                } else {
                    element.parent().parent().next('tr').find('input')[0].focus();
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/vpaqt29d/109/)

Comment: Your solution is not taking the focus to the next input element when in the age input box.
I think the proper solution would be to take the focus to the next input element in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Although your fiddle is using static contents and a fixed set of fields, below is how I achieved the solution, however, depending on the dynamic content and your requirements, the solution may vary:

```
app.directive('enterAsTab', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var elementToFocus;

                if(attrs["name"] == "personAge"){                 
                    elementToFocus = element.parent().parent().next().find('input')[0];
                }else{
                    elementToFocus = element.parent().next().find('input')[0];
                }

                if(angular.isDefined(elementToFocus))
                    elementToFocus.focus();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: it goes to the next input, but in the next <tr> , not in the same <tr>

Comment: Updated the answer as per your fiddle.